# "ion-datetime" showing incorrect time

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

I have this ion-datetime

```
<ion-datetime item-end placeholder="Select date" displayFormat="DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm" pickerFormat="DD-MM-YYYY HH-mm" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
```

The current time for me is 2:48 in GMT + 3. My problem is when I open the ion-datetime the time in popup is 11:48. I don`t want to set myDate with my current local time. Initially I want the ion-datetime to be empty.

Any idea?

Comment: What is `myDate`?

Comment: An empty variable.